# What is a good proxy for me to install and test my Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, proxy, app-config

The deployment requirements for my app (a windows service written in C#) state the presence of a Proxy server.

From my interaction with the person who will install my app:
1. His company blocks access to internet via the proxy
2. He needs to provide the path to the proxy **script** in his IE Config.
3. He also needs to input a user-name/password.

My application needs to access a publicly hosted WebService. In preparation, I sent him a test Winform app. In the app.config file I used the setting mentioned in this post [.NET client app: how to reach Web Services in case of proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127241/net-client-app-how-to-reach-web-services-in-case-of-proxy)
However, it did not work. I customized the proxy setting in App.config as per his IE settings, yet nothing seemed to work.

I don't want to hard-code the proxy settings in my app using the System.Net classes. There is no doubt in my mind that I want to use the config file.

So, I want to install a proxy on a VPC image and try and get my application to run.

My question:
1. What is a good proxy that I can install on my VM (windows only - no linux/squid pls.) that will replicate the behaviour that I mentioned in 2 & 3 above.
2. In case it is of interest, the proxy settings I used was:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy >
        <proxy usesystemdefault= “False“ proxyaddress=“http://10.1.10.10:8080“ bypassonlocal=“True“ />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Assuming that the system will read the settings from IE, I also tried

```
<proxy autoDetect="true" />
```

It did not work.

Pls. let me know if my requirements are unclear.

Comment: There are Windows Squid binaries available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open source [squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) has [Windows binaries](http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/).

If you have a Windows Server OS in you VPC, you could try out Microsoft's very own [ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/default.aspx). There's a 180-day trial version [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb738392.aspx).